# UINavigationController and UITabBarController relations is same as UIViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I started newly to learn xCode and I am using xCode 5.1

I got ready Slide-out Navigation bar form this source:

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

in this code it is required to pass my UIViewController as a parameter like this:

```
FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
```

when I do this I get this result:

[image: iphone 5s simulator]

this is AppDelegate.m code as well:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "RearViewController.h"
#import "CustomAnimationController.h"
   #import "FrontViewController.h"
  @interface AppDelegate()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>
 @end
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

        FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    revealController.delegate = self;

    //revealController.bounceBackOnOverdraw=NO;
    //revealController.stableDragOnOverdraw=YES;

    //self.viewController = revealCont;
    self.viewController = revealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and this is FrontViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface FrontViewController : UITabBarController

 @end
```

Is the problem tha navigation bar cannot handle TabBarController ?

**Edited:**
this is my FrontViewController UI.
[image]

Comment: I see your FrontViewController is only [[FrontViewController alloc] init], do you have added a childrenViewControllers to this VC ?, if not, that because is empty.

Comment: yes I added tabs and some stuff

Answer (score 1):

You are embedding your `FrontViewController` which is a `UITabBarController` inside the `UINavigationController`,which Apple doesn't allow. Apple always says NO to this. So you can look into [this](http://arm1.ru/blog/ispolzovanie-uinavigationcontroller-vmeste-s-uitabbarcontroller) tutorial. And after you do it, then try to embed it into your `SWRevealViewController`.

The tutorial just basically shows how to impliment `UITabController` and `UINavigationController`, but it doesn't show the actual answer to you questions.

What you want to achieve is actually not allow as per Apple Rules. So either you can embed your `SWRevealViewController` inside your `UITabController` OR you can remove the `UITabController` and create a custom TabBar using `UIView` and `UIButton`s and change your tab views on the `UIButton`'s -(IBAction).

Comment: You can also simply use a `UITabBar` without the `UITabBarController`, which can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil, that is trying initialize VC from XIB, my try failed.

Then I tried this succeed:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window = window;

UIViewController *firstVC = [UIViewController new];
firstVC.title = @"Title 1";

UIViewController *secondVC = [UIViewController new];
secondVC.title = @"Title 2";

UITabBarController *frontViewController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[frontViewController setViewControllers:@[firstVC, secondVC]];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = frontNavigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

You can place your VC inside Storyboard, giving him an Identifier, and call:

```
 UITabBarController *tagTBC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tagViewController"];
```